# Python BeautifulSoup findAll by "class" attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to do the following code, which is what BS documentation says to do, the only problem is that the word "class" isn't just a word. It can be found inside HTML, but it's also a python keyword which causes this code to throw an error.

So how do I do the following?

```
soup.findAll('ul', class="score")
```

Answer (score 19):

Your problem seems to be that you expect `find_all` in the soup to find an exact match for your string. [In fact](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

> When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re
>   matching against any of its CSS classes:

You can properly search for a class tag as @alKid said. You can also search with the `class_` keyword arg.

```
soup.find_all('ul', class_="score")
```

Comment: Remove the '}' from after "score". `soup.find_all('ul', class_="score")`

Comment: `class_` presumably because `class` is object keyword in python

Answer (score 12):

Here is how to do it:

```
soup.find_all('ul', {'class':"score"})
```

Comment: I tried that and that code returns this, which I do not want: <ul class="score header" id="400488971-linescoreHeader" style="display: block"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li id="400488971-lshot"> </li><li class="finalScore">T</li></ul>

Comment: Heck, i have no idea what're you doing, what are you trying to find, and where are you trying to find it. Care to give some more information?

Comment: Anyway, this will give you a list of all elements with that `score` as  the class attribute.

Comment: i want to find all elements that look like this <ul class="score"> and not find elements that look like this <ul class="score  and some other nonesense">

Comment: Okay, this is an XY problem. What do you want to do with the tag?

Comment: sorry, what is an XY problem? i am trying to get the text inside tags where it has class='score'

Comment: The text in the `ul` is this: `<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li id="400488971-lshot"> </li><li class="finalScore">T</li>` what are you expecting?

Comment: Or, make it easy. Can you show your page, and what are you trying to take?

Answer (score 0):

If OP is interested in getting the `finalScore` by going through `ul` you could solve this with a couple of lines of [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<div>
    <ul class="score header" id="400488971-linescoreHeader" style="display: block">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li id="400488971-lshot"> </li>
      <li class="finalScore">T</li>
    </ul>
<div>
"""

soup = Soup(html)
soup.find("ul", {"class": "score"}).find("li", {"class": "finalScore"}).text
```

Which would output:

```py
'T'
```